# Swashbuckle rename Data Type in Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm putting together a web API that needs to match an external sources XML format and was looking to rename the Data Type objects in the swagger output.

It's working fine on the members of the class but I was wondering if it was possible to override the class name as well.

Example:

```
[DataContract(Name="OVERRIDECLASSNAME")]
public class TestItem
{
   [DataMember(Name="OVERRIDETHIS")]
   public string toOverride {get; set;}
}
```

In the generated output I end up seeing
Model:

```
   TestItem {
      OVERRIDETHIS (string, optional)
   }
```

I'd hope to see

OVERRIDECLASSNAME {
      OVERRIDETHIS (string, optional)
   }

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and I think I solved it now.

First of all add SchemaId in Swagger Configuration (from version 5.2.2 see https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/457):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.SchemaId(schemaIdStrategy);
        [...]
    }
```

Then add this method:

```
private static string schemaIdStrategy(Type currentClass)
{
    string returnedValue = currentClass.Name;
    foreach (var customAttributeData in currentClass.CustomAttributes)
    {
        if (customAttributeData.AttributeType.Name.ToLower() == "datacontractattribute")
        {
            foreach (var argument in customAttributeData.NamedArguments)
            {
                if (argument.MemberName.ToLower() == "name")
                {
                    returnedValue = argument.TypedValue.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return returnedValue;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Any way to do this with Swashbuckle 6 for ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty old question, but as I was looking for a similar solution, I bumped into this.
I think the code in Vincent's answer might not work.
Here is my take on it:

```
    private static string schemaIdStrategy(Type currentClass)
    {
        var dataContractAttribute = currentClass.GetCustomAttribute<DataContractAttribute>();
        return dataContractAttribute != null && dataContractAttribute.Name != null ? dataContractAttribute.Name : currentClass.Name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the thread as I am not able to use the answer with Swashbukle for AspNetCore.
I am doing this. However I am not totally happy as if the object is contain in another object it is showing its original name. For example if you have a result set that is Paged That result is shown incorrectly.So this is not a final answer but might work on simple use cases.

I am using a Schema Filter. And the object just have [JsonObject(Title="CustomName")] as I get the Title property for the data type.
First Define a class like this:

```
public class CustomNameSchema : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (schema?.Properties == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var objAttribute = context.SystemType.GetCustomAttribute<JsonObjectAttribute>();
            if( objAttribute!= default && objAttribute?.Title?.Length > 0)
            {
                schema.Title = objAttribute.Title;
            }
        }
    }
```

On the startup you must configure a SchemaFilter

```
c.SchemaFilter<CustomNameSchema>();
```