# Is it possible to give input model properties different names in the Swagger UI, without using FromQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

```
public class InputModel
{
    public string Thing { get; set; }
    public DateTime AnotherThing { get; set; }
}

public ThingController : ControllerBase
{
    public Task DoTheThing([FromQuery] int foo, [FromQuery] InputModel input)
    {
        // Elided.
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the Swagger documentation is generated for this controller, the following inputs are listed for `DoTheThing`:

> foo: int
>   Thing: string
>   AnotherThing: DateTime

Note how the last two inputs start with uppercase, because that's how they are defined in their model. **I want them to start with lowercase to be consistent with the non-complex parameters passed to the controller method** (remember, ASP.NET model binding doesn't care about casing).

The easy way to do this is to either have those properties be named starting with lowercase on the model, or apply the `FromQuery` and/or `FromBody` attribute on them. I don't want to do either of these things because the former is just nasty, and the latter is applying behaviour to properties, when I need that behaviour to  be applied on a case-by-case basis.

Ideally I'd like to be able to write something like the following (which currently doesn't work because Swashbuckle doesn't seem to know/care about the `DisplayName` or `Display` attributes):

```
public class InputModel
{
    [DisplayName("thing")]
    public string Thing { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("anotherThing")]
    public DateTime AnotherThing { get; set; }
}
```

However, I'd be happy with any solution that allows me to "rename" the model properties without changing their names.

I have looked at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations but it doesn't appear to provide this functionality.

Comment: Is my answer not working for you?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754857/customize-generated-model-names-swagger-ui

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To force all parameters to be lowercase, use the obviously-named but poorly-documented `DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase` method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
{
    ...
    o.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();
    ...
});
```

(This ended up being somewhat of an XY question, because what I wanted was a way to force all params to be described as lowercase, but couldn't find a way to do it, so I asked for a general way to modify param names.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a `IDocumentFilter` in Asp.Net Core, i am not sure that this will work in normal Asp.Net but the solution must be similar.

The DocumentFilter iterates all parameters and lowers the first letter.

```
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

/// <summary>
/// A DocumentFilter that lowers the first letter of the query parameters.
/// </summary>
public class NameDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    #region explicit interfaces

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        if (swaggerDoc.Paths.Count <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths.Values)
        {
            ToLower(path.Parameters);

            // Edit this list if you want other operations.
            var operations = new List<Operation>
            {
                path.Get,
                path.Post,
                path.Put
            };
            operations.FindAll(x => x != null)
                .ForEach(x => ToLower(x.Parameters));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Lowers the first letter of a parameter name.
    /// </summary>
    private static void ToLower(IList<IParameter> parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            // limit the renaming only to query parameters
            if (!param.In.Equals("query", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                continue;
            }
            // shouldn't happen, just to make sure
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param.Name))
            {
                continue;
            }
            param.Name = param.Name[0]
                             .ToString()
                             .ToLower() + param.Name.Substring(1);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then register die DocumentFilter in the swagger configuration:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(
            c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc(
                    "v1",
                    new Info
                    {
                        Title = "My WebSite",
                        Version = "v1"
                    });
                c.DocumentFilter<NameDocumentFilter>();
            });
```

I adjusted this code from a sample that describes enum parameters, but the same idea works for renaming.