# NSwag namespace in model names

Tags: nswag

It's possible to generate client code so that model's class names have full namespaces as prefix?

That should avoid same class name conflicts.

Example

```cs
com.foo.MyClass
```

and

```cs
it.foo.MyClass
```

Up to now what I got is `MyClass` and `MyClass2` that's not so much meaningful.

Should be better to have, in case of name collision, `ComFooMyClass` and `ItFooMyClass`.

Comment: Actually I'm running into issues where it clashes when running swaggerui because my application already has the same class names.

Comment: If using Swashbuckle see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644052/rename-model-in-swashbuckle-6-swagger-with-asp-net-core-web-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution using a custom SchemaNameGenerator instead of a custom TypeNameGenerator (where I don't have package information).

```cs
internal class MySchemaNameGenerator : DefaultSchemaNameGenerator, ISchemaNameGenerator
{
    public override string Generate(Type type)
    {
        string retValue = base.Generate(type);
        // Quite ugly but do fix the concept
        if (retValue.Equals("BaseClass"))
        {
            retValue = type.FullName.Replace(".","_");
        }
        return retValue;
    }
}
```

Always set through settings:

```cs
 app.UseSwaggerUi(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly, new SwaggerUiSettings
                {
                    SchemaNameGenerator = new MySchemaNameGenerator(),
                    ...
```

This way I get something more meaningful

```cs
"/api/test/models/base": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Test"
        ],
        "operationId": "Test_Get2",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/WebApi_Models_BaseClass"
            },
            "x-nullable": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/api/test/models/extended": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Test"
        ],
        "operationId": "Test_Get3",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/ExtendedClass"
            },
            "x-nullable": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/api/test/modelli/base": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Test"
        ],
        "operationId": "Test_Get4",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/WebApi_Modelli_BaseClass"
            },
            "x-nullable": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Even if the discriminator property for polymorphism wants the base name "BaseClass".

Comment: Here I've got two BaseClass (in my question was MyClass) in two different namespaces: WebApi.Models and WebApi.Modelli

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'SwaggerUIOptions' does not contain a definition for 'SchemaNameGenerator' and no accessible extension method 'SchemaNameGenerator' accepting a first argument of type 'SwaggerUIOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) aaaa.bbbb.WebApi.dddd C:\aaaa\bbbb\Startup.cs 247 Active

Comment: Does this require installing nuget packages to access these classes? Seems like a lot of overhead in my project to generate some classes.

Answer (score 9):

Let me update shadowsheep's answer for a more recent version of NSwag:

```
services.AddSwaggerDocument(cfg => { cfg.SchemaNameGenerator = new CustomSchemaNameGenerator(); });
```

With:

```
internal class CustomSchemaNameGenerator : ISchemaNameGenerator
{
    public string Generate(Type type)
    {
        return type.FullName.Replace(".", "_");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When using NSwag via C#, you can provide an own TypeNameGenerator (via the settings object) to customize the way how the class names are generated.

Comment: I tried setting my TypeNameGenerator with TypeNameGenerator = new MyTypeNameGenerator() but in generate I've only these parameters: JsonSchema4 schema, string typeNameHint, IEnumerable<string> reservedTypeNames so that I cannot infer package information tha's right the information I need.

Comment: When using c# OpenAPI connected service ver 1.2.2
Is it possible to (always) use full type names like “com.foo.MyClass“ or “it.foo.MyClass” in generated client code.
Im facing the same issue as OP and would hate to rename some classes just to avoid this renaming to MyClass2. Not to mention all that confusion that can result from renamed classes..

Comment: What if we cannot or don't want to use Nswag via C#, is it possible to handle when generating from CLI or the GUI app?

Answer (score 1):

Updated for `NSwag.AspNetCore` as of v13.15.10 based on @shadowsheep [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321305/2206145).

The extension method `UseSwaggerUi` has been deprecated and we should now use `UseSwaggerUi3`. This method does not provides you with a way to set your custom instance of `ISchemaNameGenerator`, instead you set this at service registration time as follows:

```cs
services.AddOpenApiDocument(configure => {
    configure.SchemaNameGenerator = new CustomSchemaNameGenerator();
});
```

For completeness I'm leaving `CustomSchemaNameGenerator` below:

```cs
class CustomSchemaNameGenerator : NJsonSchema.Generation.ISchemaNameGenerator
{
    public string Generate(Type type) => type.FullName.Replace(".", "_");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended [@Dejan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59225394/1109858) by adding an attribute to my classes.

```cs
internal class CustomSchemaNameGenerator : ISchemaNameGenerator
{
    private static List<string> exludes = new List<string> { "Presentation", "Domain", "Endpoints", "Models", "Request", "Requests", "Response", "Responses" };
    public string Generate(Type type)
    {
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes<ClientGenAttribute>(false).FirstOrDefault() is ClientGenAttribute clientGenAttribute && clientGenAttribute.Name is not null)
        {
            return clientGenAttribute.Name;
        }
        return string.Join("_", type.FullName!.Split(".").Except(exludes));
    }
}
```

I'm also cutting out some Clean Architecture common namespace parts

And the attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct)]
public class ClientGenAttribute : Attribute
{
    public readonly string Name;

    public ClientGenAttribute(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

You can then do something like this:

```cs
[ClientGen("CreateLoginRequest")]
public sealed record PresentationRequest()
{
    public required Guid ClientId { get; init; }
    public required string Email { get; init; }
    public ICollection<ClaimRequest>? Claims { get; init; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To generate full namespace. You need to setup API to return swagger with full namespace

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...  //any lines you aready have 
    c.CustomSchemaIds((type) => type.FullName); //show full namespace
}
```

You can't generate a client via NSwagStudio, you need to do via code with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/45311657/1818723

And here is ready code to generate client via own code

```
using NJsonSchema;
using NSwag;
using NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp;
using NSwag.CodeGeneration.OperationNameGenerators;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

...

public async Task<string> GetClientCode(string swaggerUrl, CSharpClientGeneratorSettings settings)
{
    settings.OperationNameGenerator = new SingleClientFromOperationIdOperationNameGenerator();
    settings.CSharpGeneratorSettings.TypeNameGenerator = new MyTypeNameGenerator();
    var swagger = await GetAsync(swaggerUrl);
    var document = await OpenApiDocument.FromJsonAsync(swagger);
    var codeGen = new CSharpClientGenerator(document, settings);

    var code = codeGen.GenerateFile();
    return code;
}

public class MyTypeNameGenerator : ITypeNameGenerator
{
    public string Generate(JsonSchema schema, string typeNameHint, IEnumerable<string> reservedTypeNames)
    {
        if (typeNameHint == null && schema.IsEnumeration && schema.Title != null)
                return schema.Title; //for method argument when expected type is IEnumerable<Enum> (swagger definition must contain title - see last link) 

        return typeNameHint;   //this contains full namespace (assuming returned in swagger definition)
    }
}

private async Task<string> GetAsync(string uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

**here about enum title**

https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2103#issuecomment-853965927